# Блок на размытом фоне

Tags: css3

Проблема такая нужно сделать не размытый блок на размытом фоне блока

index.html

```
      `<div class="FilmInfo" [ngStyle] = "{'display': drop ? 
                                             'block':'none',
                                        'background':URLS}">
            <div class="Info">
               <button (click)="GetList()"> Back to list</button>
               <button>Next</button>
            </div>
       </div>`
```

style.css

```
 `  .FilmInfo{
     filter:blur(10px);
     left:0;
     top:121px;
     height: 469%;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute ;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     z-index: 98;
   }
  .Info{
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   filter: blur(-10px);
   z-index: 100;
   }`
```

вот мои попытки

Comment: clss Info Все что в нем должно быть не размыто но сзади должен быть размытый фон

Answer (score 1):

Собственно сам механизм то не сложный
У нас должен быть родитель и два потомка

**родитель > блок1 + блок2**

размывать будем первого потомка

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://s1.1zoom.me/big7/194/USA_Skyscrapers_Boston_466431.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.items {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.item-blur {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: url(http://hddesktopwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Plain-Wallpapers-HD-A7.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: .6;
  filter: blur(3px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.item-content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-content>p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fbfbfb;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item-blur"></div>
  <div class="item-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus nostrum totam ipsa sapiente? Iusto dolor deserunt distinctio in magni est!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

так как размывать надо что то то я взял из поиска картинок первое изображение по тегу `glass` так как оно совсем не прозрачное я ему задал `opacity` и сделал его `absolute` а блок `item-content` сделал `relative` что бы он был выше абсолютного

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой плагин jQuery. Оно?
https://projectsoft-studionions.github.io/jquery.forestedglass/

Comment: А способа без привлечения jQuery нет? А то насколько знаю Angular с ним не очень дружит

Comment: Объясню принцип плагина. В блок содержащий бакгроунд вставляется абсолютный блок с индексом == 0 и `background: inherit`. К Этому блоку применяется фильтр. Выбираем clip-rect для данного блока по размеру и положению размываемого блока. Фильтр на основе SVG

Comment: Ну можно попробывать

Comment: Окей а если мне нужно размыть фон а содержащиеся внутри оставить не фильтрованым?

Comment: на info `background: inherit` попробуйте